# "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" when I try to get a CGImage by AVAssetImageGenerator

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, swift2, avasset

I'm trying to make a thumbnail image of `UIImage` from PHLivePhoto so that I can get a moment before or after the picture captured. I'm struggling with the error:

```
unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

at

```
cgImage = try? imgGenerator.copyCGImageAtTime(CMTimeMake(avAsset.duration.value / 3, avAsset.duration.timescale), actualTime: nil)
```

I'm very new to swift2 syntax. please help me to get the thumbnail.

```
func makeThubnailsFromLivePhoto(livePhoto: PHLivePhoto) -> UIImageView {
    let assetResource = PHAssetResource.assetResourcesForLivePhoto(livePhoto)
    let avAsset = AVURLAsset(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: assetResource[1].assetLocalIdentifier))
    var err: NSError? = nil
    let imgGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: avAsset)
    var cgImage: CGImage?
    var imageView: UIImageView?
    cgImage = try? imgGenerator.copyCGImageAtTime(CMTimeMake(avAsset.duration.value / 3, avAsset.duration.timescale), actualTime: nil)
    let uiImage = UIImage(CGImage: cgImage!)
    imageView = UIImageView(image: uiImage)

    imageView!.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width/2, height: self.view.bounds.height/2)
    return imageView!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that's the line that raises the error? I would much more expect that it's this line:

```
    let uiImage = UIImage(CGImage: cgImage!)
```

That's going to crash any time there's an error creating the image. You either need to use do/try/catch here to catch the errors and deal with them, or you need to use `guard-let` to validate that `cgImage` is not nil. Any time you use `!`, you're saying "I bet my program's life that this is not nil."

Similarly, this line doesn't make sense:

```
    var imageView: UIImageView?
```

You later assign `imageView` from a constructor that cannot fail. But it causes you to use `imageView!`, which could be dangerous (it happens not to be in this case, but it's hard to know that). Avoid `!` as much as you can.

In general, you should avoid this pattern of `var x: Type?` followed by `x = ...`. Instead, use the pattern `let x = ...` Type inference is an important part of Swift.

Answer (score 0):

As @RobNapier said to you in his very good answer, is very improbable that your error resides in the following line:

```
cgImage = try? imgGenerator.copyCGImageAtTime(CMTimeMake(avAsset.duration.value / 3, avAsset.duration.timescale), actualTime: nil)
```

According to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html):

> You use `try?` to handle an error by converting it to an optional value. If an error is thrown while evaluating the `try?` expression, the value of the expression is `nil`.

Your error definitely is in this line:

```
let uiImage = UIImage(CGImage: cgImage!)
```

You can fix it using optional chaining like in the following way:

```
cgImage = try? imgGenerator.copyCGImageAtTime(CMTimeMake(avAsset.duration.value / 3, avAsset.duration.timescale), actualTime: nil)

if let cgImage = cgImage {
    let uiImage = UIImage(CGImage: cgImage)
    // do the rest of your code here to return the UIImage
}
else {
   // was an error and you need to return nil or something else
}
```

Or you can use the new `guard` statement like in the following way:

```
cgImage = try? imgGenerator.copyCGImageAtTime(CMTimeMake(avAsset.duration.value / 3, avAsset.duration.timescale), actualTime: nil)

guard let cgImage = cgImage else {
    // here you need to return nil or something else you want to know the caller of the function that there was an error
}

let uiImage = UIImage(CGImage: cgImage)
imageView = UIImageView(image: uiImage)

imageView!.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width/2, height: self.view.bounds.height/2)
return imageView!
```

It's up to you what to use. I hope this help you.